# Javascript library template

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, scope, prototype

Let say that i need to create a javascript library like so:

```js
;(function(){

    var root = this;

    var Ctor = function(value) {
        this.value = value;
    };

    var _ = new Ctor(value);

    _.doSome = function(value) {
        // do some work to the value
        // if no value assigned, get the value of the previous method
    };

   _.doSome2 = function(value) {
        // do some work to the value
        // if no value assigned, get the value of the previous method
    };

   _.doSome3 = function(value) {
        // do some work to the value
        // if no value assigned, get the value of the previous method
    };

   root._ = _;

}.call(this));
```

If doSome method work the value of the _ object, and doSome2 and doSome3 too.

But what about chaining the methods like so:

```js
// the doSome2 and doSome3 work with the value of doSome
_.doSome(value).doSome2().doSome3();

// the doSome3 work with the value of doSome2 cuz it has a value
_.doSome(value).doSome2(value).doSome3();

// every method work with the value assigned to it
_.doSome(value).doSome2(value).doSome3(value); // the same as:
_.doSome(value);
_.doSome2(value);
_.doSome3(value);
```

note: methods can be chained randomly, like:

```js
_.doSome2(value).doSome().doSome3();
```

Live example: https://jsbin.com/vijehotora/edit?js,console

Comment: You may need to return from each of _.doSome2,3, and so on.Hope this blog will be useful
http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Comment: ^^ That.  Simply add `return this;` at the end of each function in order to chain the calls.

Comment: As a sidenote, might as well use the prototype to set the methods of `Ctor`, since you're using a constructor function.

Comment: It's working, thank you @Archer

Comment: It's so helpful @user2181397 thank you

Comment: I will do so @Shilly thank you

Comment: please edit the answer below, there is an example to undrstand more http://stackoverflow.com/a/33148247/2034955

Comment: You're welcome - glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var Ctor = function() {};

Ctor.prototype = {
    doSome: function(value) {
        if(value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        return this;
    },

    doSome2: function(value) {
        if(value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        return this;
    }    
};

new Ctor().doSome('value1').doSome2('value2').doSome();
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/y5sdcnyu/)

Comment: It's now working as i want, read the comments in the example: https://jsbin.com/vijehotora/edit?js,console

Comment: You are trying to return `this.value` on your methods. You have to always return `this` to make your methods chainable. Take a look at this example: (https://jsbin.com/yabidaheja/1/edit?js,console,output). The `Ctor` has the default value set to 0. Then on your method call, if it receives a value, the value is added to Ctor's value property, otherwise, it keeps Ctor's value.

Comment: But i need the final result to be a litiral string not an object,

Comment: test1.doSome().doSome(2).doSome(10).value
will return a string but i want this to return a string.

Comment: If you need to return a string, your methods can't be chainable. To keep methods chainable, I suggest you to add a new method like `getValue()` to Ctor object to return the final value, and then call him after all other methods: `test1.doSome().doSome(2).doSome(10).getValue()`

Comment: can u wrap the methods like so `_(doSome().doSome(2).doSome(10).getValue())` how to do so

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "wrap the methods". Why would you want to do that? What is your goal with that? I don't think this is possible.